# Newly bought 2.0 HDMI cables aren't working

Tags: hdmi, cable

We bought 14 boxes of new HDMI 2.0 cables (1.5m in length) over a month ago and only came around to needing them just now. I needed 3 cables at first so I unpacked them. To our surprise, none of them seem to work.

For testing I'm using my older PC with a HDMI out port on the GPU and a monitor with a HDMI in. I also tried with a newer AMD Ryzen PC with an integrated GPU and the results were the same. With our older 2.0 HDMI cables and newly bought 1.4 cables, everything is working without any issues. But plug in any of those new 2.0 cables and no dice. The PC doesn't recognize that the port is being used, the monitor shows no signal.

I don't really know much about HDMI as we mostly used VGA cables till this September. Though all of them seemed to work by simply plugging them in. Is there something I can do, or had we simply gotten unlucky by buying a defective batch of cables?

Comment: Are these branded cables (major known manufacturer) or generic manufacturer that can is unbranded?

Comment: The brand is `U-SAN` which I myself had never heard of before and the cables were  4,80 Euros per cable (I don't know if that's considered cheap or not).

Comment: Yes;  U-SAN is a generic manufacturer.  I suspect more of those cables will be bad.  I would get a refund